# Geopandas is not working. I am unable to plot the graph

Tags: python, geopandas

I have taken a sample from Kaggle of Vancouver crime. I have installed geopandas. `type(geo_df.loc[0,'geometry'])` is `shapely.geometry.point.Point`

Here is my final code.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
vancouver_map.plot(ax = ax,color='grey',alpha=0.4)
geo_df.plot(ax=ax, markersize = 20,color='red',marker ='o',label='Map')
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you try to add `plt.show()`?

Comment: What does "unable to plot" mean? Do you get an error? You don't see any plot? (in that case indeed try the suggestion to use `plt.show()`) Can you clarify?

Comment: I think i am using the wrong shape file. Here is the Github [link](https://github.com/abhishekasingh/Crimes-in-Vancouver.git)

Comment: The file name is Crime in Vancouver-Copy1.ipynb. Here is the Github [link](https://github.com/abhishekasingh/Crimes-in-Vancouver.git)